# Refactoring using Async and await in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im (very) new to react having come from a Java background.  I am trying to refactor some existing code to use Async and await.

The error is coming right before my render function() (highlighted with *****) and am getting a "/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," error and cant for the life of me figure out what is going on.  Ive tried messing around with } ) and ; and cant quite track it down.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FixedSizeGrid } from "react-window";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      specialties: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch (url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      const specialties = body.data.specialties;
      return specialties;
    })
    .then(specialties => {
      return specialties.map(({ _id, name }) => {
        return [_id, name];
      })


      .then(transformed => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: transformed,
          isLoaded: true,
          error: null
        });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: [],
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
         });
      });
    }




  render() {***********************here 
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.error.message}</span>;
    }

    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    const ITEM_HEIGHT = 35;

    return (
      <FixedSizeGrid
        columnWidth={300}
        rowHeight={35}
        itemData={this.state.specialties}
        height={ITEM_HEIGHT * this.state.specialties.length}
        width={600}
        itemSize={() => ITEM_HEIGHT}
        columnCount={2}
        rowCount={this.state.specialties.length}
      >
        {SpecialtyYielder}
      </FixedSizeGrid>
    );
  }
}

const SpecialtyYielder = ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, data, style }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        ...style,
        backgroundColor:
          (rowIndex + columnIndex) % 2 ? "beige" : "antiquewhite",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      {data[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't use `.then` when doing async/await, that's the whole point. You treat it like it's synchronous code

Comment: Ya.. why are you using await fetch there if you aren't using the response of the fetch?  The await is actually doing nothing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bracket and paren:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch (url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      const specialties = body.data.specialties;
      return specialties;
    })
    .then(specialties => {
      return specialties.map(({ _id, name }) => {
        return [_id, name];
      })
    })  // missing closing bracket and paren


      .then(transformed => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: transformed,
          isLoaded: true,
          error: null
        });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: [],
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
         });
      });
    }
```

Async/Await
Basically everywhere you used `then`, you can just use `await` instead, but in a way such that you don't need a bunch of callbacks and the logic is like synchronous code:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch (url)
      const body = await response.json()
      const specialties = body.data.specialties;
      const transformed = specialties.map(({ _id, name }) => {
        return [_id, name]
      })
      this.setState({
          specialties: transformed,
          isLoaded: true,
          error: null
      })
    }
    catch(error) {
        this.setState({
          specialties: [],
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it. 
Can you clarify what the "const specialties = body.data.specialties;" is doing?

Comment: Sure, it is retrieving the json value contained within `{ data: { specialties: (value) } }` previously fetched into the body variable.  If it were me I would probably condense specialties and the transformed .map into one line (since it's basically like a one pass comprehension), and just use `{ specialities, isLoaded: true ...`.  But this might be more readable for you, and there's certainly nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need a better text editor ;). It's in your `componentDidMount`. At the very end you're missing a `)`, to close off your `.then` block and then another curly brace to close `componentDidMount`

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch (url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      const specialties = body.data.specialties;
      return specialties;
    })
    .then(specialties => {
      return specialties.map(({ _id, name }) => {
        return [_id, name];
      })


      .then(transformed => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: transformed,
          isLoaded: true,
          error: null
        });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: [],
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
         });
      });
    })
}
```

This addresses your syntax error. The way you phrased the question made it seem like you thought the "resolution" to it was to use `async`/`await`. You obviously can still do a refactor. Are you interested in still exploring async/await?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `})` in `componentDidMount` method:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FixedSizeGrid } from "react-window";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      specialties: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch (url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      const specialties = body.data.specialties;
      return specialties;
    })
    .then(specialties => {
      return specialties.map(({ _id, name }) => {
        return [_id, name];
      })


      .then(transformed => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: transformed,
          isLoaded: true,
          error: null
        });
      })

      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          specialties: [],
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
         });
      });
    })}



  render() {




    const ITEM_HEIGHT = 35;

    return (
      <FixedSizeGrid
        columnWidth={300}
        rowHeight={35}
        itemData={this.state.specialties}
        height={ITEM_HEIGHT * this.state.specialties.length}
        width={600}
        itemSize={() => ITEM_HEIGHT}
        columnCount={2}
        rowCount={this.state.specialties.length}
      >
        {SpecialtyYielder}
      </FixedSizeGrid>
    );
  }
}

const SpecialtyYielder = ({ columnIndex, rowIndex, data, style }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        ...style,
        backgroundColor:
          (rowIndex + columnIndex) % 2 ? "beige" : "antiquewhite",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      {data[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
    </div>
  );
};
```